# JavaFX forward/backward mouse buttons

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, javafx-8

is there any way to catch more than the left/right/wheel-mouse buttons? Like mouse4 and mouse5 (located at the side).

Thanks
Limo

Comment: Probably not using the built-in API that ships with JavaFX 8.  It seems that the only defined [MouseButtons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseButton.html) for MouseEvents are NONE, MIDDLE, PRIMARY, SECONDARY.  I have no suggestions on how you would actually achieve the functionality you wish, but you might need to look to 3rd party libraries or APIs.

Comment: I have no problems with using 3rd party libs. Unfortunately I haven't found anything there either. Any hints anyone?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701036/reading-special-mousebuttons-in-java-fx-explorer-mouse